# Windows Azure: Error when deleting brokered message

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am working on a Java application that pulls messages from an Azure Service Bus queue. I am using the Java Azure API (com.microsoft.windowsazure.services). The problem that I'm experiencing is that the deletion of brokered messages after they had been processed sometimes fails.

My application pulls a message from the queue using the receiveQueueMessage() method on a ServiceBusContract object, using peek-lock receive mode. Once the message had been sucessfully processed, I remove the message from the queue by calling the deleteMessage() method (I believe this method corresponds to the Complete() method in the .NET API).

However, sometimes this method call fails. A com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException exception is logged to the console by deleteMessage(), **but** it does not throw this exception (I'll produce the output below). The exception seems to tell that the message could not be found. When this happens, the message stays in the queue. In fact, the next call to receiveQueueMessage() retrieves this message again. The deletion then fails once or twice more, and then it succeeds. The messages retrieved thereafter delete successfully.

Here is the code where the problem occurs:

```
ReceiveMessageOptions receiveOptions = ReceiveMessageOptions.DEFAULT; 
receiveOptions.setReceiveMode(ReceiveMode.PEEK_LOCK); 
BrokeredMessage message = serviceBus.receiveQueueMessage("my_queue",receiveOptions).getValue(); 
// Process the message 
System.out.println("Delete message with ID: "+message.getMessageId());
serviceBus.deleteMessage(message);
```

Here is an example of the output when the problem occurs:

```
Delete message with ID: 100790000086491
2013/01/22 12:58:29 com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.serviceBus.implementation.ServiceBusExceptionProcessor processCatch
WARNING: com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: DELETE https://voyagernetzmessaging.servicebus.windows.net/sms_queue/messages/24/efa56a1c-95e8-4cd6-931a-972eac21563a returned a response status of 404 Not Found
com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: DELETE https://voyagernetzmessaging.servicebus.windows.net/sms_queue/messages/24/efa56a1c-95e8-4cd6-931a-972eac21563a returned a response status of 404 Not Found
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.voidHandle(WebResource.java:697)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.delete(WebResource.java:261)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.serviceBus.implementation.ServiceBusRestProxy.deleteMessage(ServiceBusRestProxy.java:260)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.serviceBus.implementation.ServiceBusExceptionProcessor.deleteMessage(ServiceBusExceptionProcessor.java:176)
    at microworks.voyagernetzmessaging.smsservice.SmsSender$Runner.finalizeSms(SmsSender.java:114)
    at microworks.voyagernetzmessaging.smsservice.SmsSender$Runner.finalizeSms(SmsSender.java:119)
    at microworks.voyagernetzmessaging.smsservice.SmsSender$Runner.run(SmsSender.java:340)
com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.ServiceException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: DELETE https://voyagernetzmessaging.servicebus.windows.net/sms_queue/messages/24/efa56a1c-95e8-4cd6-931a-972eac21563a returned a response status of 404 Not Found
Response Body: <Error><Code>404</Code><Detail>The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue..TrackingId:4b112c5a-5919-4680-b6bb-e10a2c081ba3_G15_B9,TimeStamp:1/22/2013 10:58:30 AM</Detail></Error>
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.serviceBus.implementation.ServiceBusExceptionProcessor.deleteMessage(ServiceBusExceptionProcessor.java:179)
    at microworks.voyagernetzmessaging.smsservice.SmsSender$Runner.finalizeSms(SmsSender.java:114)
    at microworks.voyagernetzmessaging.smsservice.SmsSender$Runner.finalizeSms(SmsSender.java:119)
    at microworks.voyagernetzmessaging.smsservice.SmsSender$Runner.run(SmsSender.java:340)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: DELETE https://voyagernetzmessaging.servicebus.windows.net/sms_queue/messages/24/efa56a1c-95e8-4cd6-931a-972eac21563a returned a response status of 404 Not Found
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.voidHandle(WebResource.java:697)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.delete(WebResource.java:261)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.serviceBus.implementation.ServiceBusRestProxy.deleteMessage(ServiceBusRestProxy.java:260)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.serviceBus.implementation.ServiceBusExceptionProcessor.deleteMessage(ServiceBusExceptionProcessor.java:176)
    ... 3 more
```

Do note that the URI in the exception seems to refer to a different message ID (efa56a1c-95e8-4cd6-931a-972eac21563a, while the message's ID is in fact 100790000086491). I do not know if this could be a key to the failure, but I have a hunch.

Another interesting observation: it looks as though the error always happens with the first message that is retrieved from the queue after the application had been started, or after the queue had been empty. All the messages coming thereafter don't seem to ever cause this type of problem.

The queue has a lock duration of 2 minutes, and the processing of the messages takes well under that duration, so an expiring lock cannot be the cause.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you to call Complete() of BrokeredMessage class.
So in your case, try calling:

message.Complete();

When the Service bus sees Complete(), it considers the message to be consumed and removes it from the queue.

Comment: I'm using with the Java SDK, which has different methods from .NET SDK. The BrokeredMessage class does not have a Complete() method. One calls deleteMethod() to remove the message from the queue.

Answer (score 3):

The UUID that appears in the URL is a random token that the server uses to track which message is locked; it is not supposed to the be same as the message id. You can access the lock URL using `message.getLockLocation()`.

The code you have looks correct, I cannot see any obvious reason why it would fail, especially in the say you describe. Some things to check:

1. Check that the message you get is a valid message. If you peek-lock an empty queue, it will return an empty message. Then the lock location should be `null`. (But that would not cause the failure you see.)
2. You could get the `lock supplied is invalid` error if you are trying to delete the same message more than once. That could happen if you have code that notices when the service returns an empty message, and substitutes the previous message. (But that would not explain why trying to delete the message eventually works, unless it is a different message that is getting deleted.)

Hopefully that will help!